# Plotting Pins on Map in WinRT

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

In my metro app using XAML and C# I need to plot some Pins on the Map control. I found several samples which all of them having plot the pins in the code behind file(add pin as children to the map control). Is it possible in another way? (similar to Windows Phone)

Comment: what kind of another way, please specify. Non windows phone developer can't get your problem.

Comment: I think on Windows Phone you have layers and ItemsControls that have items that can be bound to a collection of objects with geographical coordinates, like pushpins, routes or areas. Not sure if it's different on Windows 8.

Comment: @FilipSkakun, I only wish the W8 map was in parity to WP. You currently can't effectively bind (yet).

Comment: That sucks. Sounds like an opportunity to write an attached behavior that would support binding these pins...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom control that derives from ItemsControl. It will monitor changes to a backing ObservableCollection in your ViewModel. Then, you can just add/subtract pins from that.

Note: This is not necessarily a simple task. There is a reason there are companies creating complex controls for profit, and this is certainly a more complex one. It's not nearly impossible, but it will take some work to accomplish, much less successfully.

To get you started, it will most likely need:

- Some kind of backing Map image
- The ability to convert coordinates in the Pin to (x,y) pixel coordinates on the map image

You'll most likely need to override:

- MeasureOverride : Find out how much space the map needs
- ArrangeOverride : Find out where all of the current children go
- OnDisconnectVisualChildren : What to do when you remove a pin
- PrepareContainerForItemOverride : Creating an item container for items added/removed

You can then go on to add things like childtransitions (so they 'pop in').

Then, all you need to do is set up your VM, load your pins, and you're off to the races.

Good coding!

Comment: You had better explain how you plot the points on the map when the user pans around the globe. I think your mental solution has some practical problems. The best is going to AddPin() and RemovePin() methods that interact directly with the map layer.

Comment: I figured those would basically be PrepareContainerForItemOverride and OnDisconnectVisualChildren respectively, no?